# Override or add to [GeoExt.ux PrintPreview] rotation

Tags: geoext, boundless-suite, sdk, openlayers-2, heron-mapping-client

I'm using suite-sdk (GXP) to build my WMS client. I want add to PrintPreview window capability of changing rotation. I find this feature in Heron script but there is other version of [GeoExt.ux PrintPreview]  [link](https://gist.github.com/gpprojekt/6354109#file-newprintpreview-js). So I add

```
printRotationPage: null,
printRotationExtent: null,
printRotationExtentOptions: null,
```

and

```
if (this.showRotation) {
    this.printRotationPage = new GeoExt.data.PrintPage({
        printProvider: this.printProvider
    });
    this.printRotationExtent = new GeoExt.plugins.PrintExtent(Ext.applyIf({
        pages: [this.printRotationPage],
        layer: this.initialConfig.layer
    }, this.printRotationExtentOptions));
}
```

so file look like [this](https://gist.github.com/gpprojekt/6354109#file-newprintpreview-js).

Now when I click print icon on toolbar I get this in console:

```
TypeError: this.map is null                                                       Layer.js
    resolution = resolution || this.map.getResolution();
```

from 

`getViewPortPxFromLonLat();` function from Layer.js file.
 Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the Heron print preview is not compatible with the Suite SDK.

Comment: So maybe there is easy way to add GeoExt Print Extend to GXP Print plugin?